# Why diode in parallel with shunt resistor?

Tags: diodes, shunt

I would like to know why diode is used in parallel with shunt resistor (Current sense).

I am assuming it is to protect a shunt resistor if voltage drop is more than 0.7 (Vf of diode) in case of high current flows through the shunt resistor.

Comment: Show the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that your circuit looks like one of these two:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbEQRN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's likely that a diode in such a configuration has two protective applications:

First, as you note, in an overcurrent scenario the voltage drop across the resistor will be high, leading to a lot of power being dissipated in the shunt. The diode will start to conduct above its breakdown voltage (forward or reverse, depending on the diode polarity), causing excess current to be shunted through the diode instead.

In addition, the diode provides a clamping effect to protect the current measurement frontend. During inrush there may be a large current spike that produces a voltage drop in excess of the maximum differential voltage allowed by the measurement amplifier. The diode will clamp that voltage to a safe maximum.